# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.push is not a function while using redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm getting this error Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.push is not a function while using redux thunk but while refrshing the page after error, new word is getting added to the DB.

Below is my code.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const getDictionaryAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  "dictionary/getDictAsync",
  async () => {
    let res = await fetch("https://vocabulary-app-be.herokuapp.com/dictionary");
    if (res.ok) {
      let dictData = await res.json();
      return { dictData };
    }
  }
);

export const addWordtoDictAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  "dictionary/addWordtoDictAsync",
  async (payload) => {
    let res = await fetch(
      "https://vocabulary-app-be.herokuapp.com/dictionary",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ word: payload.word }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    if (res.ok) {
      let data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      return { data };
    }
  }
);

const dictionarySlice = createSlice({
  name: "dictionary",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getDictionaryAsync.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      return action.payload.dictData;
    },
    [addWordtoDictAsync.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload.data + "reducer");
      state.push(action.payload.data);
    },
  },
});

export default dictionarySlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that the first call to get the dictionary mutates the state invariant, from array to object. The JSON response object from `"https://vocabulary-app-be.herokuapp.com/dictionary"` is an object with `message` and `data` keys.

```
{
  "message": "Your data is here",
  "data": [ .... your dictionary data array ]
}
```

The `getDictionaryAsync` returns an object with `dictData` key.

```
export const getDictionaryAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  "dictionary/getDictAsync",
  async () => {
    let res = await fetch("https://vocabulary-app-be.herokuapp.com/dictionary");
    if (res.ok) {
      let dictData = await res.json();
      return { dictData }; // <-- returned in action payload
    }
  }
);
```

And the reducer case sets state to this payload value.

```
[getDictionaryAsync.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
  return action.payload.dictData;
},
```

Now your state is:

```
{
  "message": "Your data is here",
  "data": [ .... your dictionary data array ]
}
```

And can't be pushed into.

## Solution

I think you just want the `dictData.data` array as the payload, or just the `data` property straight from a returned `dictData` object.

```
export const getDictionaryAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  "dictionary/getDictAsync",
  async () => {
    let res = await fetch("https://vocabulary-app-be.herokuapp.com/dictionary");
    if (res.ok) {
      let dictData = await res.json();
      return dictData.data; // <-- returned data property as payload
    }
  }
);

...

[getDictionaryAsync.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
  return action.payload; // <-- return data payload as state
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your help to the newbie developer. Great and clear solution.